# ActionScript 3 - 1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before 1

Tags: actionscript-3, syntax-error

I try to make a Q&A box in essay format but i got the error message like this.
The location is in Layer "templnit", Line 1, Column 22

This is my code.

```
stop();

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var text_kosong:Boolean = true;

function onChangeText (e:Event)
{
if (e.currentTarget.length == 0){
    text_kosong = true;
}
else {
    text_kosong = false;
}
}

jawab1.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onChangeText);

function ke_cek(event:MouseEvent):void{
var keyword1_a:String = "ban";

var tj1:String;

tj1 = jawab1.text.toLowerCase();

if(text_kosong = false && tj1.indexOf(keyword1_a)>=0){
    hasil1.text = "BENAR"
}
else{
    hasil1.text = "SALAH"
}
}
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem line is

```
if(text_kosong = false && tj1.indexOf(keyword1_a)>=0){
```

where you use assign = operator instead of comparison == operator.

However, I also think you overcomplicate things. If the text is empty, it automatically does not contain the given sub-string, and you don't actually have to specifically check if the text is empty or not.

```
stop();

import flash.events.MouseEvent;

function ke_cek(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var keyword1_a:String = "ban";
    var tj1:String = jawab1.text.toLowerCase();
    
    if (tj1.indexOf(keyword1_a) > -1)
    {
        hasil1.text = "BENAR";
    }
    else
    {
        hasil1.text = "SALAH";
    }
}
```

P.S. Formatting your script to readability is always a good thing to do.